# Should two potentiometers be powered by same source or separate?

Tags: arduino, potentiometer

I have two potentiometers.  One measures the water in a tank up to a certain point.  The second takes over after that and measures the water above the first.  Currently I am powering both at the same time with the same pad on my Arduino Pro Mini 5v.  Would I get a more accurate measure if I used two different power pads or will the reading be the same?

Here is a illustration.

[image: potentiometer image]

Comment: There are no potentiometers in this circuit. Please clarify exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Irrelevant in this situation. All your components' tolerances/variances plus the output characteristics of your level measuring electrodes are so widely different that you will need separate functions to calculate water height from the analog signals, which will take care of any changes in output with respect to supply voltage.  Power them both from the same supply. Also these are not potentiometers.

Comment: Sorry, what are they called?  I do have two different functions in my code, one for each set of electrodes.  So I should be ok powering with one voltage source.

Comment: "Amplifiers" or "signal conditioners" maybe.